# How can I make buttons have the same size irrespective of the containing text?

Tags: html, css

I have this simple layout:

```
<form>  
<div>  
<input class="buttonStyle" type="submit" name="action" value="Press this button to do Action A">  
</div>  
<div>  
<input class="buttonStyle" type="submit" name="action" value="Press this">  
</div>  
<div>  
<input class="buttonStyle" type="submit" name="action" value="Press!">  
</div>  
</form>
```

I use this simple style so that the buttons are big and are have some space between them:

```
.buttonStyle {  
    margin-bottom: 10px;      
    border: none;  
    cursor: pointer;  
    font-size: 20px;  
    border-radius: 5px;      
}
```

The problem I have is that the buttons do not have the same size (since it seems that the size of the button is the same as the size of the text) and form a scale (i.e. big, short, shorter).
How can I make the buttons have the same size irrespective of the containing text?

Answer (score 1):

Just add a `width` property to the button CSS.

For example:

```
.buttonStyle {
    //...
    width: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

set a `width` attribute in your CSS

like so:

```
.buttonStyle {  
    margin-bottom: 10px;      
    border: none;  
    cursor: pointer;  
    font-size: 20px;  
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 200px;      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several options here. Setting a constant `width` may be one of them. You could also try `display: block`, which will make the buttons fill the entire width of their parent node.

Comment: `display: block` will allow you to drop the `<div>` wrapper around each button - with `display: block` you can use just one `<div>`. But you're right, for `<button>` and `<input>` tags you'll also need to set `width: 100%` in order to will the parent's width. Though, it should work fine for some other tags, e.g. `<li>`, `<span>`, `<a>`...

Answer (score 0):

Define some standard **"width"** for your buttons like,:

```
   .buttonStyle {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        border: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-size: 20px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        width:300px;
    }
```

I have created a fiddle too to refer: **http://jsfiddle.net/aasthatuteja/vChFX/**

Hope this helps!